# Visual Studio Team Services code not syncing with Azure website - git

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

The code is definitely pushing to Visual Studio Online. It's there. Checking in Kudu, things are being written to the deployment and locks folders, but the code is not syncing with the repository. The locks folder is empty despite the timestamp being updated (not sure if that's significant). In the deployments folder, the "active" file has been updated and contains a value like this: 3c80c6c4bc336c9799549385d8c35ba6b8e4cc45 which is the name of a folder containing info about a previous version of the code. There are a bunch of "temp" folders here too, drilling into the one that represents the latest code push, in the status.xml file:

```
<deployment>
  <id>temp-1fcaf088</id>
  <author>VSTS</author>
  <deployer>VSTS</deployer>
  <authorEmail>VSTS</authorEmail>
  <message>Synchronizing changes from VSTS ...</message>
  <progress/>
  <status>Failed</status>
  <statusText/>
  <lastSuccessEndTime/>
  <receivedTime>2017-03-01T07:55:13.8296373Z</receivedTime>
  <startTime>2017-03-01T07:55:13.8296373Z</startTime>
  <endTime>2017-03-01T07:55:18.3705755Z</endTime>
  <complete>True</complete>
  <is_temp>True</is_temp>
  <is_readonly>False</is_readonly>
</deployment>
```

and in the log.log file:

```
2017-03-01T07:55:13.9077727Z,Fetching changes.,6d1544dd-5cd5-44b2-a218-93578363eb66,0
2017-03-01T07:55:18.3393557Z,Failed to mmap. No data written: Access is denied.\r\n,,2
```

Bottom line: The code that I push to my Visual Studio Online repository from Team Explorer has stopped syncing with my Azure website. I'm using git. I probably did too many pushes, some were only two or three minutes apart. (I know, I know, but I had good reason to. I was trying different Web.config values that only applied to the live site.) How can I get my code to sync again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into the root site structure "/" in the Debug Console in Kudu and tried to delete all the top-level folders. Some things you're not allowed to delete, and you'll get an error message.

Obviously, please be careful when doing this! After trying to delete these folders I did a push and the site is now updated and everything is fine.

I haven't tested this but it may be the case that you only need to delete one root folder, e.g. the .nuget folder, so you should probably try this first. You can always delete the rest if it doesn't work.